# Error when I reload the TableView (delete row before the update)

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

This is the error...

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 4 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'
```

And the code when this error occurs is the following.

```
cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: fileUrl as URL?, placeholderImage: placeholderImage,
                                    options: [],
                                    progress: nil,
        completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in

            guard let image = image else { return }
            //print("Image arrived!")
            cell.imageView?.image = self.resizeImage(image: image, newWidth: 50)

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.usersArray.count-1, section: 0)

            self.tableview.reloadRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .none)

            cell.isHidden = false

        })
```

When I remove these two lines the error does not happen

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.usersArray.count-1, section: 0)

self.tableview.reloadRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .none)
```

But I need to reload the TableView after loading the images in the cells.

How could this be solved?, I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Where are you deleting a row?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a piece of cods in a ViewController.
Maybe it could work

```
cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: fileUrl as URL?, placeholderImage: placeholderImage,
                                options: [],
                                progress: nil,
    completed: { [weak self] (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
        guard let 'self' = self else { return }
        guard let image = image else { return }
        //print("Image arrived!")
        cell.imageView?.image = self.resizeImage(image: image, newWidth: 50)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.usersArray.count-1, section: 0)

          self.tableview.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }
        cell.isHidden = false

    })
```

Comment: This works for a moment, the problem is that I reload the TableView every time a person changes the value of a PickerView, your example served me, load the TableView every time I change the value in the PickerView, but when I do Scroll in the TableView , the app crashed. I have the Cell code inside func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell (withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

Comment: What I really need is to be able to recharge the cells when the tableview is fully loaded. I put those two lines of code to do when I load the image from the URL, but apparently I'm running that code every time I read an image and there are several, that could be the problem. I need to recharge the cells only once, when the entire tableview is loaded.

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas cellForRowAtIndex will be called when it will display on the screen, and sd_setImage (I think it is SDWebImage) will store the downloaded image for cache. So don't worry about call the code every time.

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas If you could share your code in the ViewController will be helpful, it is hard for me to find the problem from current code.

Answer (score -1):

try using begin update to start updating particular cell and end update to end particular cell, hope this will solve your problem:

```
__tableView.beginUpdates()
let rowToReload = IndexPath(row: usersArray.count - 1, section: 0)
__tableView.reloadRows(at: [rowsToReload], with: .none)
__tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: No, it does not solve the problem. Although it's being suggested so many times `begin-/endUpdates` has no effect at all when inserting/deleting/moving a single row.

Comment: @vadian The need to use `begin/endUpdates` isn't based on the number of rows. Even if you delete or reload 100 rows, you don't need to use `begin/endUpdates`. It's based on whether you make more than one call to some combination of `insert/delete/reloadRows` (regardless of the number of index paths involved) and you need the index paths between those multiple calls to be consistent or not.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I know, poorly worded. *...has no effect at all when performing a single insert/delete/move operation*